# Isomorphism between $\overline{\mathbb{C}[G \times G]}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{C}[G]} \otimes_{min} \overline{\mathbb{C}[G]}$

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, group-rings

I'm currently reading through a paper and it has a sort of throwaway line that says that we have the following isomorphism at our disposal:
$\otimes_{k=1}^{n} \overline{\mathbb{C}[G]} \simeq \overline{\mathbb{C}[G^n]}$.

Here, $G$ refers to a separable compact group (not necessarily discrete) and the tensor product of the C*-algebras is the minimal tensor product.

I've been trying to play around with it, but I just don't see how to define the isomorphism between e.g., $\overline{\mathbb{C}[G \times G]}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{C}[G]} \otimes_{min} \overline{\mathbb{C}[G]}$, where both algebras are acting on $L^2(G \times G)$ (which is the space of complex-valued, square-integrable functions w.r.t. the Haar measure).

Does anyone have a useful reference or sketch of a proof that I could take a look at?

Thanks!

Edit: For clarity, the completions refer to the norm completion of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ in $B(L^2(G))$ and the norm completion of $\mathbb{C}[G\times G]$ in $B(L^2(G \times G))$.

Comment: A suggestion, I don't know if it is useful: Can't you mimique the proof of $C(X) \otimes C(Y) \cong C(X\times Y)$?

Comment: @QuantumSpace by $C(X)$ are you referring to the space of continuous functions on $X$?

Comment: @MathFrak96 Yes.

Comment: @reuns Yes, $L^2(G \times G)$ is the complex-valued square-integrable functions on $G \times G$ w.r.t. the Haar measure. Taking the norm completion of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ in $B(L^2(G))$ and the norm completion of $\mathbb{C}[G \times G]$ in $B(L^2(G \times G))$.

Comment: And the $\otimes_{\min}$ completion for the $B(L^2(G))$ operator norm again?

Comment: @reuns Yes, exactly.

Comment: It reduces to $\overline{\Bbb{C}[G]}\otimes 1\subset \overline{\Bbb{C}[G\times G]}$

Comment: @reuns Would you be able to clarify this / flesh it out a bit more? I'm not really following. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I was confused about the operator norm given by the $\ell^1$ norm of the coefficients. But  $\overline{\Bbb{C}[G]}\otimes 1\subset \overline{\Bbb{C}[G\times G]}$ is correct, this is what you need to check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof for the discrete case. My guess is that a non-discrete analogue of this argument will provide a proof for the general case, but I have never worked with non-discrete groups to know if this actually generalizes. If it does not, I will delete this answer, just let me know.

I will denote the reduced group $C^*$-algebra by $C^*_r(\cdot)$. Note that for any group $G$ by definition we have $C^*_r(G)\cong\overline{\text{span}}\{\lambda_g^G:g\in G\}\subset\mathbb{B}(\ell^2G)$ where $\lambda^G:G\to\mathbb{B}(\ell^2G)$ is the left-regular representation, i.e. $g\mapsto\lambda^G_g$, where $\lambda_g^G(\xi^G_t)=\xi^G_{gt}$ for all $t\in G$, where $\{\xi^G_t\}_{t\in G}$ is the canonical ONB of $\ell^2G$.

Also, for $C^*$-algebras $A,B$ faithfully represented as $A\subset\mathbb{B}(H)$ and $B\subset\mathbb{B}(K)$, we have that $A\otimes B\cong\overline{\text{span}}\{a\otimes b:a\in A,b\in B\}\subset\mathbb{B}(H\otimes K)$.

Exercise for the OP: Show that if $H,K$ are hilbert spaces with ONBs $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $\{f_j\}_{j\in J}$ respectively, then $\{e_i\otimes f_j\}_{(i,j)\in I\times J}$ is an ONB for $H\otimes K$.

Let $G,H$ be discrete groups. We have that
$$C^*_r(G)\otimes C^*_r(H)\cong\overline{\text{span}}\{\lambda^G_g\otimes \lambda^H_h: g\in G,h\in H\}\subset\mathbb{B}(\ell^2G\otimes\ell^2H).$$

Let me make a brief comment on why this is true: by the above, it suffices to show that every elementary tensor $x\otimes y$ for $x\in C^*_r(G)$ and $y\in C^*_r(H)$ lies in this closed linear span. Approximate $x$ by something from $\text{span}\{\lambda_g^G:g\in G\}$ and $y$ by something from $\text{span}\{\lambda_h^H:h\in H\}$. Then $x\otimes y$ is approximated by something in $\text{span}\{\lambda_g^G\otimes\lambda_h^H:g\in G,h\in H\}$. If this part is unclear, I can add more details.

It is not hard to verify that the Hilbert spaces $\ell^2G\otimes\ell^2H$ and $\ell^2(G\times H)$ are isomorphic via the unitary operator
$$U:\ell^2G\otimes\ell^2H\to\ell^2(G\times H),$$
$$\text{ defined on the ONB by }U(\xi^G_t\otimes\xi_s^H):=\xi^{G\times H}_{(t,s)}\text{ for all }t\in G,s\in H.$$
Therefore we have an isomorphism
$$C^*_r(G)\otimes C^*_r(H)\cong\overline{\text{span}}\{U(\lambda_g^G\otimes\lambda_h^H)U^*:g\in G,h\in H\}\subset\mathbb{B}(\ell^2(G\times H))$$
On the other hand, by definition we have
$$C^*_r(G\times H)\cong\overline{\text{span}}\{\lambda_{(g,h)}^{G\times H}:g\in G,h\in H\}\subset\mathbb{B}(\ell^2(G\times H))$$

So if we show that $U(\lambda_g^G\otimes\lambda_h^H)U^*=\lambda_{(g,h)}^{G\times H}$ for all $g\in G$ and all $h\in H$, we are done. To show this it suffices to show that the operators agree on the ONB of $\ell^2(G\times H)$ namely $\{\xi^{G\times H}_{(s,t)}\}_{(s,t)\in G\times H}$. But indeed
$$U(\lambda_g^G\otimes\lambda_h^H)U^*(\xi^{G\times H}_{(s,t)})=U(\lambda_g^G\otimes\lambda_h^H)(\xi_t^G\otimes\xi_s^H)=U(\xi_{gt}^G\otimes\xi_{hs}^H)=\xi_{(gt,hs)}^{G\times H}=\lambda_{(g,h)}^{G\times H}(\xi_{(s,t)}^{G\times H})$$
as we wanted.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but why are you working with the reduced group C*-algebra? I'm using the non-reduced group C*-algebra, which is not always isomorphic to the reduced one.

Comment: @MathFrak96 Because I didn't know what you were working with. I guessed that when you were writing $\mathbb{C}[G]\subset B(L^2G)$ you were referring to the left regular representation. The "non-reduced group $C^*$-algebra" is the full group $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: No problem. I'm actually going to double-check my notes because I think I've confused myself about the different C*-algebras, so I will come back and clarify in a bit. @JustDroppedIn

Comment: @MathFrak96 If the group is not discrete, the closure of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is neither the full nor the reduced group C*-algebra.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks, yes, I see in my notes that if $G$ is discrete, then I am working with the reduced group C*-algebra. Otherwise it is a different space.

Comment: @MathFrak96 Can you please let me know if my answer is of any use to you? Because people have started to downvote this and I don't like this.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn It is useful for the discrete case but, unfortunately, not the non-discrete case. It is still helpful to look at, it just doesn't solve my problem entirely.

Comment: @MathFrak96 Well, as I said, I wanted to handle the discrete case and maybe some analogue of this could work for the non-discrete case. Anyway, since this does handle the discrete case, I will not delete it. To the downvoter: why did you downvote this? Adding partial answers when there is nothing else is not against MSE's policy.